# How can i pass object props and define state type?

Tags: typescript, axios, interface, state, react-props

I want to write a simple example with typescript. Using Axios to capture data from the api and print it to the screen using cards, but there is a problem with the types, when I give the state type, I encounter this error.If you do not specify the State type, there is no problem, it works normally. But when you type state, this kind of error occurs  What is the problem?[image]
I added picture of this code

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import SingleCard from '../components/SingleCard'
import { SingleProduct, ListProducts } from '../config/Types'
const Home = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState<ListProducts>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setData(res.data.products)
      })
  }, [])



  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {
              data.map((item, index) => {
                return <SingleCard product={item} />
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home


export interface SingleProduct {
    product: {
        title: string,
        description: string,
        price: number,
        thumbnail: string
    }
}

export interface ListProducts {
    data: SingleProduct[]
}



import React from 'react'
import { SingleProduct } from '../config/Types'


const SingleCard = ({ product }: SingleProduct) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="card" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                    <img src={product.thumbnail} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{ width: '100%', height: '200px', objectFit: 'cover' }} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{product.title}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
                        <h6>Price :{product.price} $</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SingleCard
```

Comment: it should be `data.data.map`

Comment: Okay, but still Type 'SingleProduct' is missing the following properties from type '{ title: string; description: string; price: number; thumbnail: string; }': title, description, price, thumbnail  and Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ListProducts | (() => ListProducts)'.  errors  coming

Comment: try `product={item.product}`, however the interface is seems not match the response format, I will post an answer with some suggestion about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer may not related to original problem)

Your interface usage is very confuse (and it does confuse you) to know which property store the object you want, I suggest to type the `ListProducts` and `SingleProduct` like the following:

```
type ListProducts = SingleProduct[]

export interface SingleProduct {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  price: number,
  thumbnail: string
}
```

And for `SingleCard` component, because react component only has one argument, you should not pass `SingleProduct` directly to the component. Create another interface for the component is better:

```
interface SingleCardProps {
  product: SingleProduct
}

const SingleCard = ({ product }: SingleCardProps) => {
// ...
}
```